# Wrap a text around uibutton SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextview

I need to display a text around a button.

In my view controller I have:

```
class myViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var backButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var myTitle: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        let exclusionPath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: backButton.frame)
        myText.textContainer.exclusionPaths=[exclusionPath]
    }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
         super.viewDidLoad()
         myTitle.text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit er elit lamet, consectetaur cillium adipisicing pecu"
     }

}
```

I get in the simulator

[image: in the simulator]

The expected result:

[image: expected result]

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Yes. Instead of using backButton.frame in UIBezierPath I use backButton.bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `exclusionPaths` describes it as: `An array of UIBezierPath objects representing the exclusion paths inside the receiver's bounding rectangle. Default value: nil.`

You are using the `frame` of another view to set this property, which uses a different coordinate system. Log the values of each of these properties (`frame` and `bounds` of your label, and `frame` of your button) to see how the values relate and how to translate from one to the other.

Relevant documentation: [Converting Between View Coordinate Systems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW52)